# How to insert into Matrix from Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, matrix

I want to create a matrix from a database(Retail) with two columns

```
CustomerID    Itemset
    1            1
    1            2
    1            4
    2            1
    2            5
    3            2
    3            4
    4            1
    5            2
```

This is the output I want in VB- CustomerID are columns and Itemset are Rows. '1' if an Itemset is bought by the customer else '0'

```
      1   2   3   4   5  (CustomerID)
  1   1   1   0   1   0
  2   1   0   0   0   1
  3   0   1   0   1   0
  4   1   0   0   0   0
  5   0   1   0   0   0
```

This is the Code I've constructed but it is not much. How do I loop the SQL queries? Or is this completely code wrong?

```
  Dim noofitems_row As Integer
    Dim noofCustomerID_col As Integer

    objConnection.Open()

    ObjCommand.CommandText = "select Max(Itemset) from Retail "
    noofitems_row = ObjCommand.ExecuteScalar()

    ObjCommand.CommandText = " select Max(customerID) from Retail"
    noofCustomerID_col = ObjCommand.ExecuteScalar()

    objConnection.Close()
    Dim matrix As Integer(,)
    matrix = New Integer(noofitems_row - 1, noofCustomerID_col - 1) {}


    For i = 0 To noofitems_row - 1
        For j = 0 To noofCustomerID_col - 1
            matrix(i, j) = >WHAT DO I CODE HERE?
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank You in Advance. If there is any doubt regarding the Question I shall respond as many times needed.

Comment: I think you'll want a 2-dimensional array, then use your variables i and j as the variables for the 2-d array index when looping.  I.e. array[i,j] = sqlResults [i,j]

Comment: Ok, I shall use 2D array but how do I insert values from DB to the Matrix?

Comment: @JeffOrris Can you direct me to a good 2D array VB Tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=2-d+array+vb  Sorry, I'd help you a bit however I am stuck at work trying to get home and is 1:50a where Im at.  The link is a bunch of Youtube videos to choose from

Comment: Iterate the entries of the table and set the according entry in the matrix to 1. Leave the other entries untouched.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Sir you have answered my last few questions. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: I think in your matrix in column 3 in rows 2 and 4 the value should be 1 !?

Answer (score 0):

> My Answer is in c#, But use it as an algorithm.

At first you need to read your data by something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
string conString = objConnection.ConnectionString;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
new SqlDataAdapter(query, conString).Fill(dt);
```

Now you have your data in a `DataTabl dt`.

When you declare an array of `int` its default values are `0`, And you need just to find and update some places to `1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int itemSet = Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Itemset"].ToString());
    int customerID = Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["CustomerID"].ToString());
    /*Update [itemSet,customerID] and [customerID,itemSet] of array*/
}
```